# Javascript widget cross-domain authentication

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have some javascript code for a widget on whateveryouwant.com that does a bunch of jsonp request to my mymaindomain.com. Every instance of the widget has his own appid, so that each appid has one, and only one, trusted domain name associated to it. Now I want to know if a single istance of my widget (appid) is being used from his trusted domain and, if true, give access to my service (returning an access token for example), and block any other untrusted domain. I read something about iframes and postmessage stuff, but i don't understand if this could be a crossbrowser solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, it sounds like you need to communicate with two widgets on different domains on the same website. If this is the case, there are two ways around the cross-domain issues if you want to avoid any server-side infrastructure or browser plugins:

1. HTML 5 has a postmessage API but this, as far as I know, is still unsupported in IE. Take a look here if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage
2. Use an old trick where you, basically, set data in an iframe and navigate the frame between the two different servers so each widget can access it one at a time. Here is a barebones example: http://onlineaspect.com/uploads/postmessage/parent.html

Comment: And how can i be, let's say, 99% sure that nobody else can access to the service if not in the trusted domain list. Am i supposed to make all the requests through the iframe?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what you're trying to accomplish. You keep mentioning service; is this service something that exists server-side or is this something client-side (like another widget)? What I mentioned is good for client to client communication over different domain names while on the same web page.

Comment: In the question I mentioned this script does some jsonp requests, so as you can imagine this widget is a javascript client for a server side API-like service.